# PHP - Convert ereg to preg_match but it's still giving an error

Tags: php, preg-match

I've converted all of my files from `ereg` to `preg_match`, but I'm still having difficulties with one line. I've made multiple changes with delimiters, changed the single quote ' to double ", backslashed and forward slashed, and it's still throwing this error:

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier 'b' in /home/casper13/public_html/youbetcha/core/core.template.php on line 2267
```

Original code:

```
$cache_override = array('member');

    foreach ($cache_override as $val)
    {
        if (ereg('^/'.$val.'/', $IN->URI))
        {
            $query->row['cache'] = 'n';
        }
    }
```

I've updated the ereg line to:

```
if (preg_match('@^/@'.$val.'/', $IN->URI))
```

Also:

```
if (preg_match("@^/@".$val.'/', $IN->URI))
```

Also:

```
if (preg_match('@\^/@'.$val.'/', $IN->URI))
```

I've tried many different ways, and still the same error. Not a PHP programmer, but I've researched all over the net, and while I fixed 100's of the lines, this one is just not working. Can you give an old gal a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delimiters for a Perl regular expression should be at the start and at the end of a pattern, the latter optionally followed by modifier characters.

```
if (preg_match('@^/'.$val.'/@', $IN->URI))
```

should work fine, provided your $val doesn't ever contain the @ character (otherwise you would have to escape it, or pick a different delimiter character for the regexp).

Comment: Also wanted to say thank you for the explanation. If I run into this again, I understand what you're saying about the pattern. I will be able to find and fix in the future.

Comment: You're welcome, I was in your shoes not so long ago, and I then decided to learn preg the right way, an investment i never regreted afterwards :-). The php manual section about PCRE is invaluably helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a delimiter mixup. The delimiter must be the first and last character in the regexp (followed only by optional modifiers). Your regexp starts with `@` and end it with `/`, which will not work. Try this (using `|` as delimiter, you can choose what you want as long as it doesn't exist in `$val`):

```
if (preg_match("|^/$val/|", $IN->URI));
```